# Finding minimum by passing a variable to recursive function with yield

Tags: python, python-2.7, yield

Let us say the `space = [0, 100]`.

I am given fragments of the space, and possibly overlap.

For example,

```
[0, 30], [0, 20], [10, 40], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

is a set of fragments.

An example of a set of fragments that span the entire space chosen from the above set is:

```
[0, 30], [10, 40], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

This set of fragments span the entire space because it has all elements in [0, 100]

Another example is

```
[0, 30], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

which is the set in the previous example without `[10, 40]`.

For each set of fragments, a cost can be calculated.

The cost of a set is the sum of marginal costs of adding a fragment.

The function for the marginal cost of adding a fragment to the set is given by:

```
def get_marginal_cost(fragment):
    return RTT + (fragment[1] - fragment[0])/bandwidth
```

where `RTT` and `bandwidth` are constants.

I am trying to find the subset from the set of fragments that has the minimum cost.

Since this cannot be solved with a greedy algorithm, I want to consider all possible sets of fragments.

I used `Depth First Search` algorithm to consider all possible cases, by considering each fragment as `node`, and defining that there exists an `edge` between fragment `u` and `v` if `u[0] < v[0] <= u[1] <= v[1]`.

Leaf nodes are fragments that ends with 100.

I was able to get the generator objects that represents (probably) all possible cases of the sets of fragments that make up a whole `space`, by the function below.

```
def dfs(a, start, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = [start, ]
    if start[1] == space:
        yield path
    for frgmt in a - set(path):
        l = frgmt[0]
        r = frgmt[1]
        if start[0] < l <= start[1] <= r:
            yield dfs(a, frgmt, path + [frgmt, ])
```

However, I am not sure how I could use the `get_marginal_cost` function I mentioned above inside my `dfs` function and how I could pass and update a `minimum` variable to `dfs` function so that I could find the minimum cost on the termination of the program.

It should keep adding marginal cost to the minimum value, and check and update the minimum only in `if start[1] == space:` (space is 100).

A test case and the code is in http://ideone.com/oN4jWa

Comment: It looks to me like you need to pass in and out of dfs not just the path but also the cost thus far.

Comment: What are "all possible sets of fragments"? That should be a given and not just all pairs of numbers within space [0, 100], right? Otherwise I would imagine the less fragments involved the smaller the cost.

Comment: Since your cost function only involves the marginal cost in addition of a fragment. I imagine with each new additional fragment, the cost is added: `previous score +  get_marginal_cost(fragmt)`. It appears that the less fragment it involves the less the cost.

Comment: Not necessarily. The marginal cost involves two factors, the number of fragments and the length of the fragments.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the definition of the length of the fragment?

Comment: I want to consider all cases(subsets) of fragments from the given set of fragments.

Comment: For [30, 50], length is 50 - 30 = 20. If RTT = 15 and bandwidth = 10, marginal cost of adding this fragment is 15+20×10. For details please see the sample code at the ideone link in my post.

Comment: I've seen it. You say "I am trying to find the subset from the set of fragments that has the minimum cost." However, unless fragment length can be negative, the best subset is an empty set. So I think you haven't delineated your problem correctly. Or I still misunderstand you. Sorry. I still don't understand why you would use a generator. Look at the bunch of for loops. I'm guessing you want to use return instead of yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I didn't understand your existing code well enough to see exactly where you're going wrong (it's not clear what `a`, or `start` are in `dfs`, for instance). However, I think I grasp the problem you're trying to solve. Here's how I'd solve it myself, using the basic algorithm you described:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def dfs(space, fragments, path=None, cost=0):
    if path == None:
        path = []
        path_end = space[0]
    else:
        path_end = path[-1][1]

    for i, fragment in enumerate(fragments):
        if fragment[0] > path_end: # this fragment would leave a gap (as
            break                  # will all the rest) so we can stop
        elif path_end < fragment[1]: # useless fragments are skipped
            new_path = path + [fragment]
            new_cost = cost + get_marginal_cost(fragment)
            if fragment[1] == space[1]:  # this fragment reaches the end,
                yield new_path, new_cost # so this is a base case
            else:     # recursive case
                for result in dfs(space, fragments[i+1:], # slice frag list
                                  new_path, new_cost):
                    yield result # in Python 3.3 and later, you can skip the
                                 # loop and just use "yield from dfs(...)"

def find_minimum_cost_path(space, fragments):
    fragments.sort(key=itemgetter(0)) # sort by start of the fragments
    path, cost = min(dfs(space, fragments), key=itemgetter(1))
    return path
```

I solved the issue of finding the minimum cost path by splitting up the work between finding all valid paths (using a recursive depth first traversal), and selecting the minimum cost path (with a call to `min`). You probably could change the `dfs` to only return the lowest cost of the paths it has found, but that would be a bit more complicated. I've kept the parts separate for simplicity.

They key to my `dfs` function is that it only works on sorted sequences of fragments. It isn't clear what kind of data structure you're using, so I've got a call to `sorted` in the `find_minimum_cost_path` function. If your fragments are already sorted (by their start element) and their data structure can be sliced, you can get rid of that step.